# Vertically aligned div not behaving when taller than viewport

Tags: html, css

I have a simple layout of a fixed header and a full height content area. Inside the content area I have a vertically aligned div which is all well and good until a lot of content is added into it.

https://jsfiddle.net/sdt3scdr/2/

HTML:

```
<header><h1>Header</h1></header>
<div id="main">
    <div class="inner">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <!-- 
            <p>Everything goes horribly wrong when there's too much content.</p>
            <p>Everything goes horribly wrong when there's too much content.</p> 
            <p>Everything goes horribly wrong when there's too much content.</p> 
            <p>Everything goes horribly wrong when there's too much content.</p> 
            <p>Everything goes horribly wrong when there's too much content.</p> 
            <p>Everything goes horribly wrong when there's too much content.</p> 
            <p>Everything goes horribly wrong when there's too much content.</p> 
            <p>Everything goes horribly wrong when there's too much content.</p> 
            <p>Everything goes horribly wrong when there's too much content.</p> 
            <p>Everything goes horribly wrong when there's too much content.</p>
            <p>Everything goes horribly wrong when there's too much content.</p>
            <p>Everything goes horribly wrong when there's too much content.</p> 
            <p>Everything goes horribly wrong when there's too much content.</p> 
            <p>Everything goes horribly wrong when there's too much content.</p> 

            ...
            ...
            ...

        -->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 1.75em;
}

header {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: blue;
    color: #222;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}

#main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 80px);
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color: red;
}

.inner {
    max-width: 800px;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 150%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
}
```

What I'd like to happen is for the inner div to scroll when there is a lot of content as if the **transform** and **top** attributes were turned off.

I don't think that a media query would work as the breakpoint would depend on the length of the content.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably adding 
`max-height:100%; overflow:auto;` to your `.inner` will help?

https://jsfiddle.net/sdt3scdr/4/

Comment: Thanks - Doing this, when there is minimal content (comment out the extra paragraphs) the vertical centering is lost.